# Need help with database table design

Tags: database-design

I want to store last 5 days stats for a user in database. I have two types of db table design in my mind.

**Design 1:**

```
id      user_name   stats
1        Peter       54             //Day 1 stats for Peter
2         Peter       50             //Day 2 stats for Peter
3         Abc         10             //Day 1 stats for Abc
4         Peter       55             //Day 3 stats for Peter
5         Abc         14             //Day 2 stats for Abc.
```

**Design 2:**

```
id  user_name   day1    day2    day3    day4   day5
1    Peter       54      50      55       -      -
2     Abc        10      14       -       -      -
```

Which of the above two is better ? 
Since I want stats for *only* last 5 days, thats why I want to overwrite the oldest day stats when adding new day so that at any time there are maximum 5 days stats for the user.
Please tell me how that should be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Design 1 is far superior.  If you decide you want to record more days in future, you don't want to have to write another set of queries to get to this data.  I presume you meant to have a 'day' column in Design 1?  Why not have a DateTime field to indicate the day like so:

```
id    user_name      day           stats
1     Peter          31-Mar-2011   54
2     Peter          01-Apr-2011   24
3     Abc            01-Apr-2011   23
```

Then you can purge the data at your own convenience.  The id primary key field is simply to simplify row identification when used in queries / updates.

Answer (score 0):

I like this more:

**id**   **UserID**    **value**  **day**

```
1        0       54     1        //Day 1 stats for Peter
2        0      50     2        //Day 2 stats for Peter
```

**Table Users**

```
id Name
0  Peter
```

In case you want to add or remove more days you don't have to change the table definition.

For speed you can create and index by UserId

Answer (score 0):

Design 1 is better, and it's not close.

In Design 1, you can do queries like

```
select user_name, avg(stats) as average from user group by user_name order by avg(stats)
```

In Design 2, any query that involves aggregating data, finding the minimum or sorting will be very cumbersome at best.

Plus, one day you might decide to store data from the last 7 days instead of 5, and with Design 2, you'll have to alter the database definition.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should just make 1 more table, "stats" table.

I have something like that in my mind :

**tbl_users**

id  user_name

```
1    Peter
2     Abc
```

**tbl_stats**

```
id  num_tbl_users_id   value
1    1                 50
2    1                 53
3    1                 54
4    2                 51
```

and then just adapt your SQL query to retrieve only the last 5 records.

```
SELECT tbl_users.user_name, tbl_stats.value 
FROM tbl_users 
INNER JOIN tbl_stats ON tbl_users.id = tbl_stats.num_tbl_users_id 
WHERE tbl_users.id = 1 
ORDER BY tbl_stats.id DESC LIMIT 5;
```

Answer (score -1):

second on table design work efficiently rather than first one because in second design its is easily to manage no. of days and user, and also first design is also looks like complex after some record inserted...

Comment: April Fools, methinks? Mehopes?